# kendo UI Uncaught TypeError: e.bind is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

I am using kendo MVVM and kendo observable extend object to bind data from an Ajax call.

In my object I am setting the data to a property in the Ajax call after the Ajax call has succeeded. I can successfully get the data to bind and show up. But, in the console, I get an error that is "Uncaught TypeError: e.bind is not a function". I have looked everywhere to see if anyone has experienced this issue before or might know what might triggers this error, but no luck...

Here is some of the javascript code:

```
(function (global) {
  kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    servicePlans : "",
    getServicePlans: function () {
       var that = this;

       $.ajax({
           url: 'services-data.json',
           type: 'get',
           dataType: 'json',
           error: function(response){
               console.log('error')
           },
           success: function(response){
               that.set("servicePlans", response.sPlans);
           }
       });
    }
    app.servicesPlansData = {
        viewModel: new servicesPlansViewModel()
    };
 })(window);

 $(document).ready(function(){
    app.servicesPlansData.viewModel.getServicePlans();
    kendo.bind($('.page'), app.servicesPlansData.viewModel);
 });
```

And some of the html:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="servicePlans-template">

<div class="plan">

  <div class="drawer-tab">
    <div class="plan-name">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: planName">
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the code?

Comment: @Vennik I've included my code in the updated comment

Comment: Judging from this code I would say kendo is not correct initialized.

Comment: I don't understand how i'm incorrectly initializing kendo